# OneToMany mapping not working in the Controller crud Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, rest, maven, api, spring-boot

I don't know how to solve the 500 status response by the api. I am testing with Postman.

The request

```
{
        "nome": "Ciencia da Computação",
        "totalCreditos": 2333,
        "professor": {
            "id": 2,
            "matricula": 0,
            "nome": "José da silva"
    }
}
```

How do I implement One to many relationship and expose the api the correct way for CRUD operation.
I'm getting a 500 error.
I don't know if I need to change the Controller functions

CursoController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/curso"})
public class CursoController {
    @Autowired
    private CursoService cursoService;
    private ProfessorService professorService;

    @PostMapping
    public Curso create(@RequestBody Curso curso){
        return cursoService.create(curso);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public Curso findOne(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return cursoService.findById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public Curso update(@RequestBody Curso Curso){
        return cursoService.update(Curso);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path ={"/{id}"})
    public Curso delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return cursoService.delete(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List findAll(){
        return cursoService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Curso.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long codigo;
    @Column
    private Long totalCreditos;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = 
    CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "professor_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Professor professor;


}
```

Comment: also can you share Professor entity class here?also share serviceimpl class as well.

Comment: can you share curso pojo class?

Answer (score 1):

you should never use CascadeType.ALL on @ManyToOne since entity state transitions should propagate from Parent entities to Child ones.

Remove

```
(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = 
    CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

from

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = 
    CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

and add it in

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = 
        CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

side.

**Explanation :**

As vladmihalcea explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) and in his book, [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://vladmihalcea.com/books/high-performance-java-persistence/), you should never use `CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToOne` since [entity state transitions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) should propagate from Parent entities to Child ones.

The `@ManyToOne` side is always the Child association since it should map the underlying FK.

Therefore, move the `CascadeType.ALL` from the `@ManyToOne` association to the `@OneToMany` which should use the `mappedBy` attribute since it's [the most efficient one-to-many mapping](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).
`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `CascadeType.ALL` whitch Cascade all operations (`PERSIST,MERGE,REMOVE,REFRESH,DETACH`).
For more details you can take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html#ALL)